# Prettify / Beautify HTML in Perl

Tags: perl

I have some HTML output sitting in a variable that I will like to Prettify / Beautify but struggling to make sense out of the results of my web searches.

Most of the options I have found such as PerlTidy (Not even sure it is a correct option) appear to assume that the HTML is in a file but in my case, it has been put together in a Perl script and stored in a variable and I just wanted to fix this by removing excess line breaks and indenting and then saving this to another variable before sending to output.

Looking for something along the lines of

```
$output= SomePerlModule::Prettify($HTML);
```

Which I can hopefully jut add to my exiting script.

A bonus will be if it can also remove orphaned end tags. Basically, I have some end tags such as  without start tags and while the browsers seem to be able to deal with this, it would be nice to strip these out.

Is there such a module?

Comment: maybe `XML::LibXML` can help? method `load_xml ` reads files and strings, method `toString` serializes in different modes. (well, input has to be a valid XML chunk)

Comment: The example in the HTML::Tidy documentation shows it uses the `source` parameter as a variable (which is what was requested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML::Tidy](http://p3rl.org/HTML::Tidy) does exactly that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Tidy;

my $str = '<div><p>Text<h2>Heading</h2>';
my $tidy = 'HTML::Tidy'->new;
print $tidy->clean($str);
```

**output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="tidyp for Linux (v1.04), see www.w3.org">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>Text</p>
<h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a shot once I get back to my dev machine. Just wondering, does this indent the html or sort it out flat against the left hand side?

Comment: @Dayo: Just pass `{ INDENT => 1 }` to the constructor to turn indentation on.

Comment: Struggling with installing HTML::Tidy. Will evaluate once done.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you generate valid HTML in the first place. Come up with the correct template, and fill it in.

Instead, it looks like you are using `print` statements in Perl to generate the HTML. One day, post-processing will do the wrong thing, and you will have no idea what went wrong where and how to fix it.

Filling in a template avoids all these issues. Any template module is better than `print`ing HTML, but [Template.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Manual) has a great ecosystem.

Given that the HTML is not under your control, you might want to also consider [HTML::PrettyPrinter](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::PrettyPrinter) if [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) generates the correct syntax tree for your HTML.

Comment: The html generation is not fully under my control otherwise I'll have sorted it out at a lower level.